# Rigging cloth to follow only part of a mesh

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to create a character that has a blanket over its legs. I want to be able to move the feet underneath the blanket to make the blanket move, however I'm having a hard time achieving this. I've tried following other tutorials on rigging clothes but they make the blanket stand up straight and not move correctly, or completely deform depending on how I did it. I was thinking it had to do something with weight painting but I wasn't sure. I messed around with it a bit but still couldn't get it to do what I wanted. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. I'm a complete novice at blender so any help is much appreciated!!

[image: Before parenting]
[image: After parenting]

Comment: You don't provide a lot of information so that people can help you.  I would not focus on weight painting, however.  It appears that the cloth "collides" properly against you character and gurney in the first picture.  You may want to edit your question to add what the second picture is about -- is it a later frame where the character moves?

Comment: If you move your leg left or right under a blanket it won't go that way. The blanket will move up and down according where the leg rise it. So you can't solve this with rigging, you have to use only simulation.

Comment: Yes, the cloth collides fine when the character is still, but when the animation starts the blanket doesn't react at all. So when I tried parenting it to the bones in the feet, the blanket stands up straight and is kind of deformed. Then any movement of the feet affect the whole blanket instead of just a little part. If there's anything else I can add to make it clearer please let me know! @james_t

Comment: I would not parent to any other object, especially armature.  You want pure cloth simulation with your two Collision objects.  Try adjusting the Collision objects Cloth *Thickness*.  I usually reduce the default *inner* to be the same as the *outer* of 0.02.  If you can get a small enough test-case file.  Look at https://youtu.be/NQLdrXndnQU